# Best Practice for Wordpress Theme Functionality

Tags: wordpress

Regarding Wordpress:
Is it best practice to distribute a functions.php file (to be stuck in a WP theme) filled with helpful functions, or distribute a plugin for wordpress that enables these functions anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends. It depends on how coupled those functions are with the theme itself. If the functions are only useful for that theme, or you don't plan on making a lot of themes, just leave them in the functions.php file. If the functions are more general, and you could see yourself or someone else wanting to use them in other themes, you may want to make them a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic ideas about the use of functions.php files in [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) at WP.